# Using a react component as the value of a key / value pair in a object - typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have an object with a key / value pair.

```
import { CarIcon } from 'components/Icons';

export interface Map {
  [name: string]: string;
}

const Icons: Map = {
  cars: () => <CarIcon altt="f" />,
};

export default Icons;
```

I want to loop through the object in a seperate component, and render the component ie the value. It actually works fine, however I'm getting the following typescript error which will cause build issues

> Type '() => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

Any ideas here?

Comment: Seems straightforward enough. You've declared `Icons` to be of type `Map`. You have `Map` as a type which accepts `string` keys, and those keys map to `string` values. You have assigned to the `cars` key a value which is not a `string`, and so you get an error. Perhaps consider changing the type of your `Map` to allow its values to be functional react components: `Map { [name: string]: (props: any) => JSX.Element }`.